# ROS2, set parameters from file and directly?

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have one parameter which is defined inside the python launch file (multiple nodes use this parameter), and the other parameters should be loaded from a parameter file.

Is it possible to use a parameter file and to set parameters directly in a python launch file at the same time? In the documentation, I did not find a way to handle this. It looks like, it is only possible to set a parameter file or to define the parameters directly.

```
    trajectory_visualization_param = get_param_file('arg_trajectory_visualization, 'arg_trajectory_visualization.param.yaml')

    trajectory_source = "p3"

    trajectory_visualization_velocity_planner_node = Node(
              package="arg_trajectory_chunk_provider",
              node_executable="arg_trajectory_visualization",
              node_name="arg_trajectory_visualization_velocity_planner",
              parameters=[{"trajectory_source": trajectory_source}],
              node_namespace=vehicle_ns
              )
```

I do not want to have something like a global parameter server.
https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-global-parameters/

Is there a way to handle this nicely, or how would you handle this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368802/ros2,-set-parameters-from-file-and-directly?/) by [mschratter](https://answers.ros.org/users/51444/mschratter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-01-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be done as of ROS Foxy.

To set a single parameter on all nodes in the same scope of a launch file, you can use the [SetParameter](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/2f09c6414c58f0a4a34305bd44be30b850af2b60/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/set_parameter.py#L33) action. The parameter will be set on all nodes launched after the `SetParameter` action, also applying to any included launch files.

For example, to set the ROS parameter `use_sim_time` for all nodes in a launch file, you can something like

```
import launch
import launch_ros.actions

def generate_launch_description():
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.SetParameter(name='use_sim_time', value=True),
        # 'use_sim_time' will be set on all nodes following the line above
    ])
```

This is also supported in front-end launch files, for example XML:

```
<launch>
  <set_parameter name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
  <!-- 'use_sim_time' will be set on all nodes following the line above -->
</launch>
```

Note, you can use a launch "group" to scope the `SetParameter` action. In the following example, the talker node does not have the `use_sim_time` parameter set, but the listener node does:

```
<launch>
  <group>
    <set_parameter name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <node name="listener" pkg="demo_nodes_cpp" exec="listener" output="screen" />
  </group>
  <node name="talker" pkg="demo_nodes_cpp" exec="talker" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

I'll add that it's currently **not** possible to set parameters from a parameters file in a similar way, though it would be interesting to add such a feature.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2021-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-04-21**:
Have you tried using "double-star" syntax in a YAML file?

```
/**:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
```

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2021-04-22**:
The issue is that the YAML file must be passed to each Node action in the launch file. It would be nice to have an option to set a parameters YAML file with a global action in launch, such that it will be automatically passed to all nodes. I'm not sure it is straight-forward to implement such a launch action though.